# I cannot update my system with `pacman`

Tags: pacman, artix-linux

Trying to update my system, I get the error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies).

This is what I get:

```
~> sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronising package databases...
 gremlins is up to date
 system is up to date
 world is up to date
 galaxy-gremlins is up to date
 galaxy is up to date
 lib32 is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace libcanberra-pulse with gremlins/libcanberra? [Y/n] n
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing expat (2.4.1-1) breaks dependency 'expat=2.3.0' required by lib32-expat
:: installing libcap (2.50-1) breaks dependency 'libcap=2.49' required by lib32-libcap
:: installing libelf (0.185-1) breaks dependency 'libelf=0.184' required by lib32-libelf
:: installing libcanberra (0.30+2+gc0620e4-4) breaks dependency 'libcanberra=0.30+2+gc0620e4-3' required by libcanberra-pulse
```

I then try to remove the package `expat`, but I get the message: "Attention: There are forbidden packages in the removal list!"

I looked at this [web page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251478), but here they can uninstall the problematic package, while I cannot, since `expat` is part of core.

What should I do at this point?

Comment: You cannot uninstall `lib32-expat`, `lib32-libcap`, `lib32-libelf` and `libcanberra`? Those are the packages you should uninstall; after which, you should rebuild them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages in `lib32` repository, which are 32-bit versions of various libraries and such, depend on their 64-bit counterparts of the same version.

You have the unstable testing repositories, such as `gremlins` and `galaxy-gremlins`, which provide newer versions of packages such as `expat`. But you do not have `lib32-gremlins` repository, so you do not get the same updates to the 32-bit counterparts of those packages, i.e. you get to stay on the old(stable) ones. And, since the stable 32-bit packages like `lib32-expat` depend on the 64-bit counterpart packages from the stable repos, there is a conflict, in that you can either keep your system older (to satisfy the old 32-bit package dependencies), or install the newer 64-bit packages (which will break the 32-bit package dependencies, meaning you can do that only by uninstalling such).

Alternatively, you can enable `lib32-gremlins` repository, which provides 32-bit versions of packages in the 64-bit testing repositories, or disable all testing repositories - any of these two actions will get your 64-bit and 32-bit repositories in sync and dependencies solvable with latest available packages.

Comment: I would enable the `lib32-gremlins` repository. Could you show me the command to do it? Thank you.

Comment: The same way you enabled the other testing repositories - check `/etc/pacman.conf`, and uncomment the section regarding the repository. Don't forget to also uncomment the `[lib32-gremlins]` line, that isn't just a comment.